# can i derive the following identity without expanding the sum notation then combining it

Tags: sequences-and-series

the following identity ${\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{k=1}}(n+k)^3 = \displaystyle\sum^{2n}_{k=1}k^3 - \displaystyle\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^3$ was shown on my textbook and there was no explanation about it.

I want to derive the identity without expanding the sum notation,

1. can I prove the identity without expanding the sum notation of both sides
2. how can I derive the identity from the left without knowing the right

Comment: Change of index

Comment: I'd suggest you write out all the terms explicitly for some small $n$, say 4, and it should become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
$$
\sum^{2n}_{k=1}k^3 =  \sum^{n}_{k=1}k^3 + \sum^{2n}_{j=n+1}j^3
$$
For the last sum, rename the index  to $k = j-n$, which gives
$$
\sum^{2n}_{k=1}k^3 =  \sum^{n}_{k=1}k^3 + \sum^{n}_{k =1}(n+k)^3
$$
which is what you want.

So this was not dependent on the 3rd power function. Indeed, you could write for any function $f$:
$$
\sum^{2n}_{k=1}f(k) =  \sum^{n}_{k=1}f(k) + \sum^{n}_{k =1}f(n+k)
$$